# Haskell Pattern matching in let on function return vs function arguments

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

As a beginner at Haskell I've found it difficult to visually recognize some examples of pattern matching.

It seems that in let bindings sometimes the pattern matching occurs on the lhs when a function is called and the values are bound to variables in the equation on the rhs like in the following code example:

```
let boot x y z = x * y + z in boot 3 4 2
```

Sometimes however a function will be run in the rhs and the **return** values of that function will be bound to values in the lhs of the equation as in the definition of the State Monad from "Learn you a Haskell":

```
instance Monad (State s) where  
    return x = State $ \s -> (x,s)  
    (State h) >>= f = State $ \s -> let (a, newState) = h s  
                                        (State g) = f a  
                                    in  g newState
```

where the function h is run with the lambda argument s and the return values are bound to (a, newState).

To a new Haskell programmer, this is slightly confusing.  I could imagine a scenario where you might have:

```
let f a b = g c d in ...
```

where the function g would return a function and two arguments as it's return values.  In this case would the "f a b" need to be wrapped in parenthesis for the pattern match to occur?  I'm trying to find a definitive explanation of how the pattern matching occurs.

I have read most of "Learn You A Haskell For Great Good", as well as snippets from "Real World Haskell" and "A Gentle Introduction to Haskell" and I have not found a clear explanation of how to determine if the pattern matching should be occuring on arguments to a function or on the return values of a function. Any help in clearing this up would be appreciated.

Comment: `return a function and two arguments as it's return values` <- this is impossible. You can only match on data constructors, not general expressions. In your example, `State` and `(,)` are constructors.

Comment: In `(a, newState) = h s`, the function `h` returns a [tuple](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Lists_and_tuples#Tuples)...

Comment: @melpomene, I think this is the distinction I was looking for, if there is a data constructor on the lhs, then the pattern matching is occuring on the return values of the rhs correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're stumbling over the difference between [function and pattern bindings](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-830004.4.3).

In short, if you have something like "*variable* *pat1* *pat2* ... =" (where *pat1* *pat2* ... are one or more patterns), it's a function binding; otherwise it's a pattern binding. In the most simple case, `x y z = ...`, a function binding is just syntactic sugar for a lambda: `x = \y z -> ...`.

If it starts with a `(`, it's not a variable, so the whole thing must be a pattern binding. But even without parens `State x` is still a pattern binding because `State` is not a variable (it starts with an uppercase letter so it must be a constructor).